# Yii2: Create a condition for Submit form button

Tags: forms, button, yii2, submit, conditional-statements

I'm fairly new to yii so I guess this must be a very easy question to answer. I'm trying to create a condition for the submit button. What I want is for the user to not be able to press the submit button if they have created a form previously.

This is the code snippet and what I'm trying:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <?=
        $id = Yii::$app->user->getId();
        $exists = AsdaPa0026::model()->exist('id_asda_pa_0025='.$id);


         if($exists){
            echo " you have already filled a form ";
         }
          else{

           Html::submitButton('Someter', ['class' => 'btn btn-success']);
          }
          ?>

</div>
```

I get the **Call to undefined method frontend\models\AsdaPa0026::model() error**
It's probably a syntax error but I'm not sure how should I make it work. Any help would be very appreciated.

Comment: `::model()` is a Yii 1.1 syntax. If you're using Yii 2 you probably need to use `::find()->where(['id_asda_pa_0025' => $id])->exist()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this query.

```
<div class="form-group">
    <?=
        $id = Yii::$app->user->getId();
        $exists = AsdaPa0026::findOne(['id_asda_pa_0025'=>$id]);

         if($exists){
            echo " you have already filled a form ";
         }
          else{

          echo Html::submitButton('Someter', ['class' => 'btn btn-success']);
          }
          ?>
```